# How do I print the results that you get in the console to a text file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm really stuck on this assignment. The idea is to print out the results of this code to both console and to a text file. I want the result to look like it does look in the console. Don't mind the comments that are in swedish. I can't seem to get the code to print as i would like it. Can anyone help? I have experimented a bit in the bottom with StreamWriter as well.

This is an example of what I would like to print in a text file:
"
1 salespersons has reached level 1: less than 50 articles:
Anton | 1234567890 | Sweden | 23

2 salespersons has reached level 3: 100-199 articles:
Ben | 1234567891 | Russia | 165
John | 1234567892 | Norway | 133 "

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Examination2
{
    public class Sales //Här börjar jag hela projektet med att skapa en klass som innehåller all info som skall samlas på säljarna
    {
        public string Name
        { get; set; } // get set för tydlighet, (set { this.Name = value; })

        public string Ssn
        { get; set; }

        public string District
        { get; set; }

        public int Articles
        { get; set; }

        public int Level
        {
            get // Ändrar värdet på nivån efter värde på Articles med en default på 0 om något inte skulle stämma. 
            {
                if (Articles < 50)
                    return 1;
                if (Articles > 49 && Articles < 100)
                    return 2;
                if (Articles > 99 && Articles < 200)
                    return 3;
                if (Articles > 199)
                    return 4;

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var saleslist = new List<Sales>(); // börjar med att göra en lista med ett välkomstmeddelande och sumSales-antal säljare. 
            string levelOnePrint = null;
            string levelTwoPrint = null;
            string levelThreePrint = null;
            string levelFourPrint = null;
            string ppOne = null;


            Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to LTU sales bonus system");
            Console.Write("Please enter the amount of salespersons you want to register: ");
            int sumSales = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < sumSales; i++) // här loopar jag igenom det antal säljare som är inmatat med en for-loop för att kunna spara informationen i listan. 
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the following info for salesperson number {0}, press enter after each entry: ", i + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("|  Name  |  Social Security Number  |  District  |  Sold Articles  | ");

                saleslist.Add(new Sales() // sparar inmatade värdet de olika instanserna jag gjort av klassen Sales till de olika variablerna.
                {
                    Name = Console.ReadLine(),
                    Ssn = Console.ReadLine(),
                    District = Console.ReadLine(),
                    Articles = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                });

            }

            var peopleByLevel = saleslist
            .GroupBy(p => p.Level).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
            Console.WriteLine("\n");                                            // queries för att kunna gruppera säljarna
            Console.WriteLine("Name | SSN | District | Articles");
                                                                                // Groupby, ToDictionay(som fungerar på lists och arrays) och ToList.
                                                                                // Jag använde todictionary och tolist för att värdet först blev en array när jag groupade, sen konverterade jag till list.
            if (peopleByLevel.ContainsKey(1))                                   // här gör jag ett par if-statements för fullfölja raderna innan, level 1:
            {
                var levelOne = peopleByLevel[1];
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelOne.Count} salespersons has reached level 1: less than 50 articles:"); // kommentar för tydlighet    
                levelOnePrint = $"{levelOne.Count} salespersons has reached level 1: less than 50 articles:";

                var levelOneSort = levelOne.OrderBy(p => p.Articles);
                PrintPeople(levelOneSort);
                ppOne = (levelOneSort).ToString();
            }

            if (peopleByLevel.ContainsKey(2)) // level 2
            {
                var levelTwo = peopleByLevel[2];
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelTwo.Count} salespersons has reached level 2: 50-99 articles:"); // kommentar
                levelTwoPrint = $"{levelTwo.Count} salespersons has reached level 2: 50-99 articles:";

                var levelTwoSort = levelTwo.OrderBy(p => p.Articles);
                PrintPeople(levelTwoSort);
            }

            if (peopleByLevel.ContainsKey(3)) // level 3
            {
                var levelThree = peopleByLevel[3];
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelThree.Count} salespersons has reached level 3: 100-199 articles:"); // kommentar
                levelThreePrint = $"{levelThree.Count} salespersons has reached level 3: 100-199 articles:";

                var levelThreeSort = levelThree.OrderBy(p => p.Articles);
                PrintPeople(levelThreeSort);
            }

            if (peopleByLevel.ContainsKey(4)) // level 4
            {
                var levelFour = peopleByLevel[4];
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine($"{levelFour.Count} salespersons has reached level 4: More than 199 articles:"); //kommentar
                levelFourPrint = $"{levelFour.Count} salespersons has reached level 4: More than 199 articles:";

                var levelFourSort = levelFour.OrderBy(p => p.Articles);
                PrintPeople(levelFourSort);
            }

            static void PrintPeople(IEnumerable<Sales> people) // metod för att printa ut all info i slutet
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\Temp\MyTest.txt";

                foreach (var p in people)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} | {p.Ssn} | {p.District} | {p.Articles}");

                    Printfile(levelOnePrint, levelTwoPrint, levelThreePrint, levelFourPrint);
                }
            }



            static void Printfile(string one, string two, string three, string four)
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\Temp\MyTest.txt";
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

                    lines.Add(one);
                    lines.Add(two);
                    lines.Add(three);
                    lines.Add(four);
                    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
                }

                else
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(one);
                        sw.WriteLine(two);
                        sw.WriteLine(three);
                        sw.WriteLine(four);
                    }
                }
            }

            Printfile(levelOnePrint, levelTwoPrint, levelThreePrint, levelFourPrint);
           
        }

    }






}
```

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Comment: There is not one error but the code is not even compiling. @Anton, please take care that when you ask for help you deliver code what at least compiles. You added the levelOnePrint ect at last moment without compiling.

Comment: You need to remove `static` statement from `Printfile` and `PrintPeople` to make the code compile. As I could see, the file is being recorded successfully, you are just not telling the code to record the person names.

Comment: Well, the biggest problem I have right now is finding a good way for me to print out the names aswell as the "salespersons has reached level 4: More than 199 articles:" comments. Right now it only prints out the comments of how many people are in the different levels. I don't know where to add the print commands to make it print out for instance: 

1 person in level 4:    
Anton | 12345 | Sweden | 213 |
    
1 person in level 3:     
John | 12345 | Norway | 159 |

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` modifier from `PrintPeople` method and it should compile properly.